# querying a multiindex pandas dataframe with slices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, querying

Assuming I have the following multiindex DF
import pandas as pd

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
input_id = np.array(['12345'])
docType = np.array(['pre','pub','app','dw'])
docId = np.array(['34455667'])
sec_type = np.array(['bib','abs','cl','de'])
sec_ids = np.array(['x-y','z-k'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([input_id,docType,docId,sec_type,sec_ids])
content= [str(randint(1,10))+ '##' + str(randint(1,10)) for i in range(len(index))]
df = pd.DataFrame(content, index=index, columns=['content'])
df.rename_axis(index=['input_id','docType','docId','secType','sec_ids'], inplace=True)
df
```

I know that I can query a multiindex DF as follows:

```
# querying a multiindex DF
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,['pub','pre'],:,'de',:]]
```

basically with the help of pd.IndexSlice I can pass the values I want for every of the indexes. In the above case I want the resulting DF where the second index is 'pub' OR 'pre' and the 4th one is 'de'.

I am looking for the way to pass a range of values to the query. something like multiindex 3 beeing between 34567 and 45657. Assume those are integers.

```
pseudocode: df.loc[idx[:,['pub','pre'],XXXXX,'de',:]]
XXXX = ?
```

EDIT 1:
docId column index is of text type, probably its necessary to change it first to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `query` is very powerful:

```
df.query('docType in ["pub","pre"] and ("34455667" <= docId <= "3445568") and (secType=="de")')
```

Output:

```
                                          content
input_id docType docId    secType sec_ids        
12345    pre     34455667 de      x-y        2##9
                                  z-k        6##1
         pub     34455667 de      x-y        6##5
                                  z-k        9##8
```